# I get a red curve line when using f-string

Tags: javascript, python, html

```py
def email_verification(email,password):
        message = Mail(
            from_email='hesheitaliabu@gmail.com',
            to_emails=email,
            subject='HEY BABYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',
            html_content=f"""
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    
                <body>
                    <button onclick="myFunction()">Replace document</button>

                <script>
                function myFunction() {
                window.location.href = "email_verify/" + email + "/" + password;
                }
                </script>
                </body>
                </html>
                """)
        Sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key=os.environ.get('MyAPI'))
        Sg.send(message)
```

I have define a function called "email_verification" on FLASK to send the email with HTML design. I have used the f-string for the HTML content. But, I get a red curve line under the line of **window.location.href = "email_verify/" + email + "/" + password;**.

Comment: Such a line is created by the IDE or text editor you are using. It should somehow give you more hints what is wrong.

Comment: What does it say when you hover over the red underlined text?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code. The first error It says that "window" is not defined and the second error is Unexpected token at end of expressionPylance

Comment: For real-world applications, sticking a password in a url like this is _not_ a good idea.

Comment: Since your string is an f-string, perhaps python is trying to parse the values within braces as template replacements.

Comment: Thank you the error is gone. But, when i clicked the button, it won't jump to another page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape literal braces `{}` in f-Strings in python.

You do this by doubling them. e.g.

```py
def email_verification(email,password):
        message = Mail(
            from_email='hesheitaliabu@gmail.com',
            to_emails=email,
            subject='HEY BABYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',
            html_content=f"""
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    
                <body>
                    <button onclick="myFunction()">Replace document</button>

                <script>
                function myFunction() {{
                window.location.href = "email_verify/" + email + "/" + password;
                }}
                </script>
                </body>
                </html>
                """)
        Sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key=os.environ.get('MyAPI'))
        Sg.send(message)
```

Notice here in the syntax highlighting how the body of `myFunction` is part of the f-String (green) and not a template variable (white) as in your question.

See https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#braces